# ofstream leaking memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, ofstream

I have a C++ class that writes its data out to a binary `std::ofstream`.  The class is storing the data as a `boost:shared_array` but I have eliminated this as the problem.  The problem is with the call to `write()` on the `ofstream`.

The issue is that it seems to leak memory.  The system it is running on is CentOS 64bit, GCC 4.1.2.

When looking at `top` and `free` when the application is running the executable itself does not continue to consume memory (as backed up by the memory profiler in Netbeans), but the amount of free system memory does decrease over time.  What's more, **when the application exits this memory is not reclaimed!**

This is a particular issue because the intention is to write out to disk continuously at around 50MB/s for hours on end.  However, once we get down to around 90MB of free system memory it seems to "stabilize" and not reduce any further and the application continues to run OK.  It does however screw up the system for the other running processes, which is bad, mmkay.

Below is an ever-so slightly simplified version of the class that is causing the grief.

```
class WritableMessage
{
public:
    WritableMessage();
    void write(std::ofstream* const idxStream, std::ofstream* const dataStream);

private:
    IdxRecord m_idx;
    boost::shared_array<char> m_data;
};
```

The ofstreams are initialised and destructed elsewhere but essentially they remain open for writing "forever".

```
void WritableMessage::write(std::ofstream* const idxStream, std::ofstream* const dataStream)
{
    //Call the IdxRecord to write itself (just a call to idxStream->write())
    m_idx.write(idxStream, dataStream->tellp());

    //This is the main issue, because this data can be up to about 2MB in size
    //for each write.  Commenting out this line removes all issues with the memory leak
    dataStream->write(m_data.get(), m_idx.getMessageSize());

    //I'd expect the flush to clear any buffers that the ofstream maintains,
    //but apparently not
    idxStream->flush();
    dataStream->flush();
}
```

Comment: If it isn't reclaimed at process death, it isn't the process' memory. Could it be that this is disk cache allocated by the OS? The fact that it only uses memory down to a certain amount seems to indicate that, too.

Comment: `when the application is running the executable itself does not continue to consume memory (as backed up by the memory profiler in Netbeans), but the amount of free system memory does decrease over time. What's more, when the application exits this memory is not reclaimed!` Highly suspect.

Comment: Use a leak checker to determine leaks. valgrind comes to mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a problem, and that is just the system cache working as intended.
Linux is very agressive on caching, so it will use almost all your free memory for this, but whenever an application needs more memory, it will release some of that memory and grant it to the application.

Comment: That is indeed very odd, or at least confusing.  Especially given that once the `ofstream` has done the write I never open the file for input using an `ifstream`, so there is never a need to cache anything once it has been written to the disk.  And that it doesn't release the memory once the program exists looks just plain wrong.  I do notice that running up the program again frees up the cache instantly giving me the memory "back" before eating it all up again.

Comment: The system can't know beforehand that nobody will use the written data. Since it's already at RAM when you write, it's "free" to just keep it in the hope that it may be useful in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Use vmstat ([man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?vmstat))

```
vmstat -S m 1
```

It will show you cache and buffer memory. Note that buffer memory is volatile and will be freed automatically as soon as an application requests it.

I can easily show the effect on my 8GB desktop (linux) by logging in, and merely doing 'dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null'; the buffer memory will steadily consume *all* of available memory.

This is by design

Some pertinent links:

- http://sourcefrog.net/weblog/software/linux-kernel/free-mem.html
- http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/fs/filesystem.html
- [Google search : linux memory free available cache buffer](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=linux%20memory%20free%20available%20cache%20buffer)

Comment: Thanks, I can see that and see that it is reclaimed when required.  Is there a way to release the cache when the program exits or when the `ofstreams` have been closed?  I don't think explaining to a customer why our application isn't really using 99% of the available memory despite all signs saying it is being too easy!

Comment: This is a non-problem. Just point them at the documentation for their linux distribution. Teach them to monitor actual memory usage in top/htop. If you insist: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` (`echo 3` to drop page, inode _and_ dentry caches). Now, you'd have to run that as root (ick!). _Surely_ you understand that you should have bigger trouble explaining why you need to run your app _as root_ (only in order to: (a) cosmetically fake simple memstats (b) trash server performance by annihilating useful cache!)

Comment: We're actually monitoring the memory usage using SNMP, which just reports the usage as 99%.

Comment: @fwgx: you're doing it wrong :) fix the monitoring. To be fair, I hope your monitoring software actually supports something more sensible than the metric it's giving right now :)